# How do I define a set of statements of the form x∈A in set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to define a set with set builder notation where all elements are of the form "*x* ∈ A." For example, with a set B = {*x* ∈ A, *y* ∈ A, ... , *z* ∈ A} it would be tempting to define B as B = {*a* ∈ A | *a* ∈ A} but in this case "*a* ∈ A" is just taken to mean "*a*" which is an element of "A" so it would be that B = {*x* , *y*, ..., *z*} which is not what I want. How would one define a set of statements, such as B, in set builder notation without making it misleading?

Comment: What does "of the form $x\in A$" mean? Either $x$ is also in $A$ or $x$ is not in $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't understand, why not just write $A$? $A$ is the set of all elements $x \in A$.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What exactly are you trying to ask? As @AlephZero rightly said, $A$ is the set of every $a\in A$. Why not just write A?.

Comment: I don't want B to be the set of all elements in A; I want B to be the set of all "statements," such as "x is an element of A," "y is an element of A," and so forth.

Comment: What about defining $\phi(x)=x \in A$, and defining the set as $B = \{\phi(a) \mid a \in A\}$?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work for what I am doing, thank you.

Comment: Or define that the elements are statements, then something like $B = \{"a\in A" \mid a \in A\}$?

Comment: Also, is each element the proposition that $x\in A$, or is it the string "$x \in A$" which represents the proposition?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, each element is the proposition that "$x \in A$", but each proposition doesn't necessarily have to be true; for example if $A$ was the set of all days it will rain and $D$ was the set of all days of the week and I wanted $B$ to be the set of all statements "it will rain on $x$" for all $x \in D$ then I would want $B = \{[Sun] \in A, [Mon] \in A, ... \}$ but each statement is not necessarily true.